# Why does setting an object from an interface value throw invalidCastException only on a one line if statement

Tags: vb.net, interface

When setting an array object using an if statement that contains Interfaces, I get an InvalidCastException thrown and need to understand why

I know how to fix the actual issue, i am just confused why this happens.

Please notice the customerOne and Two are interfaces (i.e. ICustomer), and customers is an array of "Customer" (not the interface)

This only goes wrong when its an array, if I try to set a single object to an interface value it works fine

```
Dim customerOne as ICustomer
Dim customerTwo as ICustomer
```

---^^ these get populated... then we create an array:

```
Dim customers as Customer()
```

Now, the odd part...

```
customers = {customerOne, customerTwo}
```

The above works fine

```
customers = If(myBool, {customerOne,customerTwo}, {customerOne,customerTwo})
```

The above fails with InvalidCastException

I would expect that the If statement would return the exact same value as the working example and therefore not throw an InvalidCastException

Does anyone understand the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Arrays are covariant in .NET, a regretful Java feature.  That requires the framework to check that the array elements do in fact implement the expected class, that normally happens when you access the array element.  And sometimes happens when you don't expect it, like in that If-statement.  Just an early warning that the code isn't correct.  We can't see the concrete classes you used, but significant odds that you must declare the array as ICustomer().  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance/

Comment: The if statement returns an array of ICustomer which can't be casted to Customer. While the other one creates an array of Customer and cast each element one at a time.

Comment: @the_lotus thank you : )    So, even though the result of the If statement is exactly the same as setting the values direct.... the If version will choose to use ICustomer.  Do you know why it would behave different?

Comment: @trendy the if() is like a method and needs a return value, it will look at the parameters and decide that the return value should be ICustomer().

Comment: @the_lotus can you write your comments as an answer please so i can vote it up

Comment: Steven has updated his answer with details about the IF difference, thank you for your help @the_lotus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code only compiles because you have `Option Strict Off`, which allows certain errors to slip under the RADAR at compile time only to be discovered via exceptions at run-time.  If you turn `Option Strict On` (which I, and most others, would suggest that you do), event this line fails to compile:

```
customers = {customerOne, customerTwo}
```

The error it gives is:

> BC30512  Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'ICustomer' to 'Customer'

The reason for that is because the expression `{customerOne, customerTwo}` evaluates to an array of `ICustomer` objects, since that is the type of the variables.  There is no way, at compile time, for the compiler to know that those two variables will definitely reference `Customer` objects since they could theoretically reference any type of object which happens to implement the interface.  Therefore, the best it can do is to determine the type of the array based on the variables given in its initializer.

So, that expression evaluates to an `ICustomer()` array, but the variable you are trying to assign it to is a `Customer()` array.  Since `Customer` is more specific than `ICustomer`, that assignment isn't automatically allowed.  In order to get it to compile, you'd have to explicitly cast it.  Either you can cast the items in the array initializer, to get it to evaluate to the right type of array:

```
customers = {DirectCast(customerOne, Customer), DirectCast(customerTwo, Customer)}
```

Or, using a little LINQ, you could allow it to evaluate to the wrong type of array and then just cast the whole array:

```
customers = {customerOne, customerTwo}.Cast(Of Customer)().ToArray()
```

However, neither of those options are safe.  They both allow for type-checking exceptions to occur at run-time.  So, if at all possible, it would be better to rewrite your code in such a way that it allows the compiler to do all its type checking safely at compile time.  For instance, if you change the `customers` variable to be an array of `ICustomer` instead of an array of the concrete `Customer` type, then it would work fine:

```
Option Strict On

Public Module MyModule
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim myBool As Boolean = False
        Dim customerOne As ICustomer = New Customer()
        Dim customerTwo As ICustomer = New Customer()
        Dim customers As ICustomer()

        ' Both of these lines compile fine because the arrays are all ICustomer()
        customers = {customerOne, customerTwo}
        customers = If(myBool, {customerOne, customerTwo}, {customerOne, customerTwo})
    End Sub

    Public Class Customer
        Implements ICustomer
    End Class

    Public Interface ICustomer
    End Interface
End Module
```

As far as the reason why the ternary `If` operator is throwing it off... well, that's more complicated and goes over my head.  I try to avoid using `Option Strict Off` at all costs, so how exactly it works is not my expertise.  However, at a high level, what's happening is that the `If` operator is adding an extra layer of evaluation and type inference in the middle which foils VB's attempts to do the automatic type conversion for you.  For instance, if you do this, with `Option Strict Off`, it works:

```
Dim customerOne As ICustomer = New Customer()
Dim customerTwo As ICustomer = New Customer()
Dim customers As Customer()
customers = {customerOne, customerTwo}
```

And if you do this, you'll see that what `{customerOne, customerTwo}` evaluates to is actually an `ICustomer()` array:

```
Dim customerOne As ICustomer = New Customer()
Dim customerTwo As ICustomer = New Customer()
Dim customers As Customer()
Dim temp As Object = {customerOne, customerTwo}
Console.WriteLine(temp.GetType().Name)
```

But, if you do this, it will throw an exception at run-time:

```
Dim customerOne As ICustomer = New Customer()
Dim customerTwo As ICustomer = New Customer()
Dim customers As Customer()
Dim temp As Object = {customerOne, customerTwo}
customers = temp
```

The exception it throws is:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ICustomer[]' to type 'Customer[]'

Just by splitting it up into two steps, forcing it to evaluate the input array first, it fails.  It'll only work when you create the array and assign the variable in the same command.  In fact, it fails with the same exception even when you specify the correct type on that intermediate variable:

```
Dim customerOne As ICustomer = New Customer()
Dim customerTwo As ICustomer = New Customer()
Dim customers As Customer()
Dim temp As ICustomer() = {customerOne, customerTwo}
customers = temp
```

And that's essentially what the `If` operator is doing.  It's splitting it up into two steps where the `If` operator has to first evaluate its operands to determine which type it, itself, gets evaluated to (i.e. like, what it returns, if it were a method). And that extra step in the middle stops VB from being able to automatically perform the type conversion.  Specifically why that is, I can't say.

Comment: Always great answer and great explanation

Comment: wow, what a quick answer... ill have a read through shortly (just debugging something else at moment)... but, yes, one of the changes is to add option strict and explicit to all pages, but its a big project.   I see this get highlighted and know a better way to do it, but looking forward to having a read to understand why it behaved different with the "if" statement : )
will read and get back shortly, thank you

Comment: @Steven Doggart, thank you, however I have already set customer to an interface for my fix, but my main confusion was why `customers = {customerOne, customerTwo}` worked at runtime, but the `If(myBool, {customerOne,customerTwo}, {customerOne,customerTwo})` didnt? (no idea why the "if" version would be different? any ideas? if you could add it to the answer if you know why, ill mark it as answered :)

Comment: just seen you addition at the end about the "IF" being treated as a method... it needs to determine the type to return, which is why its returning the interface type instead of my direct approach which doesnt need to... thank you : )